# How to paste a copied object to particular cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've written below code to copy a table from outlook EMail:

```
        Set objApp = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
        Set objDoc = objApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor

        objDoc.Tables(1).Range.Copy
```

I know that we can paste this copied objDoc (Which is an Object) using the line: `excWkSht.Paste` Which is pasting this randomly in a excel sheet.

I'm trying to paste this in the first cell using: `excWkSht.Cell(1, 1).Range.Paste` but it throws error

> "Run-Time Error '438':Object doesn't support this Property or method"

Can someone help me with this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821951.aspx

Worksheet.Paste allows us to choose the destination as a supplied Range. For your example, you could use:

```
excWkSht.Paste Destination:=excWkSht.Cells(1, 1)
```

Comment: You'll not believe what I'm going to say now. My previous method which was working stopped working and nothing is getting pasted in my excel sheet. Neither your method nor mine working now.

Comment: I believe it, I'm just not sure why it would happen. Have you modified the type of data you're copying, or maybe the method by which you copied?

You could also try doing copies through "Selection." Excel is sort of built around its user interface, and copy/paste normally works through the selected ranges. This is also probably why the Paste you used to be doing seemed to put things in random places - it was probably just pasting at the current selection.

Comment: The reason might sound weird. But after logging of my machine yesterday, I tried to run the macro again and it worked (Pasted randomly at one position) so I've deleted the rows, saved the excel workbook and closed it. I ran the macro again, now it doesn't paste the table. I think I'm gonna die before this macro works perfectly

Comment: Sorry I was off the work. I tried your solution today and it throws me the same error.

Comment: Yeah, well typos will do that to you. My apologies, but there is no "Cell" property for worksheets, the correct property is "Cells."

Looking at the original post you also used "Cell" instead of "Cells" so I probably hit Ctrl+C from yours and totally missed the typo. So sorry! I edited my answer and it should definitely work now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. It wored :D

Comment: can you help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446768/table-from-outlook-email-not-getting-copied question as well?